# SAS with BULKLOAD=Yes: ERROR: BCP initialize error: Unable to retrieve error message

Tags: sas, sqlbulkcopy, bulk-load

Has anyone encountered the error when trying to run in any of the bulk modes (not just bulkload=yes, but also insertbuff=xxx etc).
The related odbcbcp.dll is present in the System32 directory, so this is not the case of being unable to find it.

Runs fine w/out bulk load, but of course the speed is not even close.

SAS 9.3, Win 32-bit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with some most random luck, discovered that this may have been a bug specifically in sas 9.3, which has been subsequently eliminated in v9.4

Still an open question for those of us locked in v9.3 due to licensing.

Comment: Licensing of what? If you have a license for SAS you can install the latest version. What usually prevents that is slow company IT departments that do not want to roll out the new version to the users.

Comment: This very much depends on your licensing (eg 'for the purposes of'), and also your account manager.  Unless SAS give you access to a depot, there is no way to upgrade.  A recent client of mine got stung by this, and got 'locked' into 9.3 despite the internal IT team being very keen to roll out 9.4.